# How to checkout-copy-checkin a file in TFS using Post-build event?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, post-build-event

I have a Project holding server controls. Whenever I make changes to it I want to be able to Build in Release mode and have the output DLL (and its documentation Xml file) copied to a folder in Team Foundation Server.

I have come out with a post-build event that:

1. Checks both DLL and XML out.
2. Copies them to the TFS folder
3. Checks them back in with some comments.

This is the script:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$(DevEnvDir)tf" checkout /lock:none C:\CommonAssemblies\$(TargetFileName)
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$(DevEnvDir)tf" checkout /lock:none C:\CommonAssemblies\$(TargetName).xml
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release copy $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName) C:\CommonAssemblies\ /Y
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release copy $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).xml C:\CommonAssemblies\ /Y
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$(DevEnvDir)tf" checkin C:\CommonAssemblies\$(TargetFileName) /noprompt /comment:"File checked in automatically by Post-build action in source project."
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$(DevEnvDir)tf" checkin C:\CommonAssemblies\$(TargetName).xml /noprompt /comment:"File checked in automatically by Post-build action in source project."
```

This works, but only if there is at least one change in the code, and at least one change in any of the XML comments. If I try to build twice without any change, I get an error saying:

```
The command "if Release == Re...... " exited with code 1.
```

**How can I get rid of this error?**

From the Output window, I can read that TFS detected there were no changes in the file and it Undo the edit.

What can I add to my checkin instruction to ignore such checkin when no change is detected? I've been working so far with that script, but I must remember each time to add a random space to the code and to some comment for it to work properly. There must be something I'm missing, maybe a parameter or else.

Here's part of the text from the Output window:

```
C:\CommonAssemblies:
  Controls.dll
C:\CommonAssemblies:
  Controls.xml
          1 file(s) copied.
          1 file(s) copied.
  C:\CommonAssemblies:
  Checking in edit: Controls.dll

  Changeset #6188 checked in.
  C:\CommonAssemblies:
  Checking in edit: Controls.xml

  The following changes were not checked in because the items were not modified.
    Undoing edit: C:\CommonAssemblies\Controls.xml

  There are no remaining changes to check in.
```

Comment: Does a missing change let your build fail or do you just get the error message? The documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z(v=vs.100).aspx) shows no parameter to ignore this, but you could run a validate before doing the checkin.

Comment: When you look at the documentation of VS2012 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z(v=vs.110).aspx) the force parameter is described to to checkin even nothing changed. In VS2010 this parameter already exisits, but is not described in the docuementation, so you could give that a try.

Comment: @Mike It worked! the /force parameter seems to do the job just fine. Tks

Comment: For the record the Force parameter is a good idea when checking in any dll or exe. It seems that the algorithm Microsoft uses to detect changes isn't really that good. We ran into situation where a binary that had changed wasn't checked in because it was close enough. It didn't happen often, but enough to fix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657988/tf-error-there-are-no-remaining-changes-to-check-in) and I found the answer.

The `/force` parameter is what was missing from the checkin instruction. This checks in the file even when there are no detected changes within.

This script is no longer throwing errors:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$(DevEnvDir)tf" checkout /lock:none C:\CommonAssemblies\$(TargetFileName)
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$(DevEnvDir)tf" checkout /lock:none C:\CommonAssemblies\$(TargetName).xml
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release copy $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName) C:\CommonAssemblies\ /Y
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release copy $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).xml C:\CommonAssemblies\ /Y
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$(DevEnvDir)tf" checkin C:\CommonAssemblies\$(TargetFileName) /noprompt /force /comment:"File checked in automatically by Post-build action in source project."
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$(DevEnvDir)tf" checkin C:\CommonAssemblies\$(TargetName).xml /noprompt /force /comment:"File checked in automatically by Post-build action in source project."
```