# TF checkin ignore "no files to check in" error

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

**Background**: I am writing a batch files to create and check in some contract files (language agnostic representations of API files) whenever we check into an API project. I am checking in the files with the following command:

```
tf checkin /flags myContractFiles
```

Frequently the contract files do not change so I often get this error:

> There are no remaining changes to check in.

As a result the build fails.

**Question**: Is there a way to avoid this particular error?

**What I have tried**: I am aware of the `/force` flag for `tf checkin` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711153/how-to-checkout-copy-checkin-a-file-in-tfs-using-post-build-event)), but would rather not use it because I would prefer to only check in when there actually is a change (I do not want to pollute the branch history with changesets with no changes). I have also seen the `tf diff` and `tf folderdiff` commands, but it looks like they output their result to the command line, and I am unable to do something like this:

```
if tf folderdiff ... (
  tf checkin ...
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either have to parse the folderdiff result to do what you want or create a custom activity to detect the changes through the API.

Comment: In the end I edited the tool that was creating the contract files to also check them in if the correct command line arguments were given.

Comment: That's really not great. I would expect an option to ignore no changes.